# Tinymce - How to let the user know the shortcuts

Tags: tinymce, section508, wcag2.0, tinymce-plugins

How can we let the user know the list of shortcuts in Tinymce editor. I am doing a 508 compliant website so it should be keyboard accessible as well as the shortcuts should be play as announcement when getting focus for the blind people. Egs: If I want to use the keyboard shortcuts, the user should know that rt? One solution is to list out all shortcuts in the web page itself. Is there other option build in tinymce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you load the `help` plugin you will see a Help menu which provides access to a dialog that contains a list of the keyboard shortcuts:

[image]

Comment: Oh...Thank you Michael

Comment: what is the best practice to tell the custom keyboard shortcuts to the user? I have added alt+k as the shortcut to get focus to the toolbar menu since the default shortcut alt+F10 will not work in linux which is a nuix command to resize the window. One approach is to show a banner with this info. Is there any other way?